# jquery button value change with efffects

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I want to change the button's value with fading effect when i click on it. My code is:

html:

```
<button> some value </button>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#btn_1").click(function (){  
        $(this).prop('value', "new value!"); // line1   
    });   
});
```

From another stackoverflow answer, I found that if i replace line1 with `$(this).find('span').html('Collapse').hide().fadeIn('slow');`
and change the html part to `<button> <span> some value </span> </button>` it works. However, is there a way to achieve the transition effect using jquery without using span tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

just use `$(this).text('new value!').hide().fadeIn('slow');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_1").click(function() {
    $(this).text('new value!').hide().fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1"> some value </button>
```

Comment: @AayushKarki Cool =D

Answer (score 0):

You can set text property of button. and you can fadeOut and fadeIn

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#btn_1").click(function (){  
        
           $(this).text("You Clicked").fadeOut().fadeIn();
           
          
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">Click HERE</button>
```